# Use CSS :not Selector for inner link

Tags: css

I use a plugin on a Wordpress blog. It marks alle links to amazon with an asterix in source code (no css). I mark my custom link also with an asterix via css. So the plugin links have two asterix ** instead of one *.
I tried to fix it with the not selector but is does not work (broweser: firefox).
I want to know if its possible with :not() selector

Plugin Code:

```
<div class="plugin"><a href="amazon.com">LINK*</a></div>
```

My Code:

```
<a href="amazon.com">Link</a>
```

CSS

```
a[href*="amazon.com"]:not(.plugin a):after {content: "*"; }
```

Comment: seems to work for me https://jsfiddle.net/dmouokas/

Comment: Yeah but not for my custom link. There is no asterix. https://jsfiddle.net/dmouokas/1/

Comment: there is in Safari (which is what i am using) both have LINK*

Comment: ok. I'm using firefox

Comment: oops sorry. looks like safari accepts multiple selectors but chrome and firefox do not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a new CSS rule.

```
a[href*="amazon.com"]:after {
  content: "*"; 
}
.plugin a:after{
  content: "";
}
```

EDIT: Here is a solution that uses :not

```
:not(.plugin) > a[href*="amazon.com"]:after {
  content: "*"; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zcktfbad/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to know if its possible with :not() selector

Comment: I've worked out a way to use the :not selector, but not sure it would work in all browsers.

Comment: tested with Firefox, IE and Chrome, works on all three